# Flutter Firebase already exists

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check whether firebaseapp is already initialized before initializing it again. How to get the list of firebaseapp already exists (initialized). I am using multiple firebaseapp in my flutter mobile application.

```
PlatformException(IllegalStateException, java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name Connectors already exists!, Cause: null, Stacktrace: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name Connectors already exists!


I/flutter (29617):      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:2)

I/flutter (29617):      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:296)
I/flutter (29617):      at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.lambda$initializeApp$2$io-flutter-plugins-firebase-core-FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin(FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:142)I/flutter (29617):      at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.run(Unknown Source:8)
I/flutter (29617):      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
I/flutter (29617):      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
I/flutter (29617):      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
I/flutter (29617): , null)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See the code sample from [Flutter's Firebase documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initialization)

If you initialize Firebase in your app's entry, you can guarantee that it has both been initialized and only one time.

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using multiple firebaseapp in my flutter application. Is there anyway i can get list of firebaseapp already initialized to check before initializing.

Comment: If you are having a complex setup like that it would help if you post code sample of how you are currently trying to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, for security reasons i am not allowed to share the actual code. I just want to get the list of firebase app that's already been initialized. Firebase.apps is not giving the all list of firebaseapps already initialized.